# Progress bar never displays

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I simply want a nondeterministic progressbar that becomes visible and shows some "activity" to indicate a query is running, and then, when the query is through, goes back to being invisible. Seems simple enough; but with this code:

```
try
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    progressBarChanges.Value = 50;
    progressBarChanges.Step = 20;
    progressBarChanges.Visible = true;
    ... // the meat of the code, where the query is being done, elided
} finally
{
    progressBarChanges.Visible = false;
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

...the progress bar never displays, even though the query takes awhile to run. The progress bar is on a DGV. I realize my progress code is a bit lame, but first things first - I just want the darned thing to show *something* for starters.

### UPDATE

I am setting the progressBar to visible *way* before I'm calling the BackgroundWorker proc that runs the query:

```
progressBarChanges.Value = 50;
progressBarChanges.Step = 20;
progressBarChanges.Visible = true;
. . .    
if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    if (ValidEntryForCRID(textBoxID.Text))
    {
        RetrieveAndBindPlatypusData();
        var tb = (TextBox)Controls.Find("textBoxDuckbill", true).First();
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.Focus(); 
        }
        if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxID.Text)) &&
            (backgroundWorkerShowChanges.IsBusy != true))
        {
            backgroundWorkerShowChanges.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    . . .
```

...yet the progressBar is never becoming visible (unless I never set it back to visible = false after the DGV's DataSource is assigned the OracleDateTable value of the returned query/result set). If I comment that out, it then (belatedly) finally shows up, apparently thinking (erroneously) "better late than never."

Is there a way to force Windows to "pay attention" to the "progressBarChanges.Visible = true;" line right away? Something like a .ProcessMessages() or this.Refresh or...???

Comment: did you remember to enable the progress bar?

Comment: Why are you using `progressBarChanges.PerformStep();` ?

Comment: You might have to do the action in a thread - or else you are blocking the UI thread with your "meat".

Comment: @Desolator: out of desperation.

Comment: @BDJ: It's enabled by default (at design-time), and I don't change that.

Comment: @Ruolf: Maybe this is a clue - the query takes place in a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

I enable the ProgressBar just before the BackgroundWorker call:

```
progressBarChanges.Visible = true;
backgroundWorkerShowChanges.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The BackgroundWorker code gets the OracleDataTable from the DB:

```
private void backgroundWorkerShowChanges_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    holdChanges = GetChangesMade(textBoxID.Text);
}
```

The BackgroundWorker's "completed" event updates the UI:

```
private void backgroundWorkerShowChanges_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    PopulateChangesGrid();
}
```

In PopulateChangesGrid(), after assigning the OracleDataTable object to the DGV, I set the Progress bar invisible:

```
private void PopulateChangesGrid()
{
    dgvPlatypi.DataSource = holdChanges;
    progressBarChanges.Visible = false;
}
```

It works like a charm (<-- not necessarily a reference to Windows 8 "Metro" charms).

Comment: This is the correct/expected way to solve your problem.  Justin was probably confused by your terminology.  He provided directions on use a progress bar which indicates how much of the task has been completed and how much further you need to go.  You wanted a busy bar or busy spinner which indicates that your application is working, without any indication of how much work has been done or how much is needed.

Comment: @Trisped You are correct, and I disagree that this is the correct way to solve this...the progressbar has a style 'Marquee' that does this without the need for such boilerplate code.

Comment: Well, I did say "nondeterministic." That's a good tip on the Marquee style, though - using that I had to 86 "progressBarChanges.PerformStep();"

Answer (score 7):

This is happening because you are not giving the UI thread time to update. You are updating to visible and immediately running your code. The code should run on a background thread and send update messages.

To elaborate:

When you set the Visible property, the UI thread does not actually update until the end of that current logic. So, what is happening is this:

- Visible
- Run process
- Not Visible
- Code is complete, so UI is unfrozen and updated...with the last state being Not Visible

**What you want is:**

- Visible
- Kick off new thread to run meat
- UI Code is complete, so UI is unfrozen and updates the bar to Visible

Then this:

- ==>New thread runs meat sending updates to the UI thread so that the progress bar can update

Then this:

- New thread ends and in its final method sets Not Visible
- UI Code is complete, so UI is unfrozen and updates the bar to Not Visible

A [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) or [Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) should be pretty easy to implement this with.

**UPDATE FOR CODE TO SHOW CONSTANT SCROLL**

I believe you are only missing that the progressbar's style should be `ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`. If you already are offloading the work to a backgroundworker, then the rest should just work

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        progressBar1.Enabled = progressBar1.Visible = false;
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar1.Enabled = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = progressBar1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm already using a BackgroundWorker for the query; I tried putting the Visible = true,false code in there, too...

Comment: I reckon you mean "...updates the bar to INvisible" in the third bullet point in the first set of bullet points.

Comment: At any rate, this seems *awfully* (and I do mean *awful*) complex for something that should be so simple: 1) show a progress bar spinning madly (or doing jumping jacks or whatever) 2) run a query while the progress bar is "going" 3) When the query returns and updates the GUI with the result set, 86 the progress bar.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work - ended up being pretty easy. I'll post my steps above, appended to my original post.

Comment: On second thought, I added it as an answer.

Comment: @ClayShannon actually, I would say your method is a bit more cumbersome than mine with an unnecessary timer. I had misread that you were not really updating the progressbar, but instead needed more of a constant scroll. I have updated my answer to show how to do this. It is the full code for a quick app I just wrote to prove it works.